# Error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<bool>::atomic(const std::atomic<bool>&)’?

Tags: c++

This is my class structure/setup

```
class A {
   public:
   std::atomic_bool isStarted();
   ...
   private:
   std::atomic_bool started;
}

std::atomic_bool A::isStarted() {
    return started;
}
```

This all compiles fine but when I have an instance of A

and attempt to invoke a.isStarted(), I get this error

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<bool>::atomic(const std::atomic<bool>&)’
 return started;
        ^~~~~~~
```

How should I go about restructuring the isStarted function to not invoke this deleted function? I don't understand why the copy constructor is being invoked when I'm just returning the boolean field.

Comment: you cant return `std::atomic` from `isStarted`, return `bool` instead

Comment: You are not "just returning the boolean field". You are returning an object of a class type `std::atomic_bool`. This involves its construction, and the required constructors are deleted for this class.

Answer (score 3):

Current version returns `atomic_bool` by value, this will use deleted copy constructor, you can change the function to return reference to your class member, like this `std::atomic_bool& A::isStarted()`

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

> std::atomic is neither copyable nor movable.

Comment: @DanielLangr  I think this part of my answer does answer the question, `you can change the function to return reference to your class member, like this std::atomic_bool& A::isStarted()`

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I overlooked myself. Even though returning a reference to an atomic class member looks a bit "suspicious". Returning a simple `bool` will mostly likely make more sense.

Comment: @DanielLangr Surely there are setups when returning a simple bool instead of reference to atomic bool can cause race conditions. That's what I had in mind giving this answer. To make sure you don't change class members you can add `const` modifier to function signature.

Comment: The problem with `const` is that then, you can basically only read its value through the returned reference. Which you can as well by calling a function that returns `bool`. A reference just adds a possibility to control ordering.